# Scraping data from multiple URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wish to scrape data from [a link]http://cbfcindia.gov.in/html/SearchDetails.aspx?mid=1&Loc=Backlog!
 , However the MID parameter is incremental in URL to give 2nd, 3rd URL ..... till 1000 URLs, so how shall I deal with this(I am new to PYTHON AND SCRAPY, so dont mind me asking this)?

Please check the XPATH i have used to extract the information, it is fetching no output, is there elementary error in the spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from movie.items import MovieItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'movie'
    allowed_domains= ["http://cbfcindia.gov.in/"]
    start_urls = ["http://cbfcindia.gov.in/html/SearchDetails.aspx?mid=1&Loc=Backlog"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//body")    #Check
        print titles
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
          print "in FOR loop"
          item = MovieItem()
                  item ["movie_name"]=hxs.xpath('//TABLE[@id="Table2"]/TR[2]/TD[2]/text()').extract()
          print "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  movie name:", item["movie_name"]
          item ["movie_language"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="lblLanguage"]/text()').extract()
          item ["movie_category"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="lblRegion"]/text()').extract()
          item ["regional_office"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="lblCertNo"]/text()').extract()
          item ["certificate_no"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="Label1"]/text()').extract()
          item ["certificate_date"] = hxs.xpath('//*@id="lblCertificateLength"]/text()').extract()
          item ["length"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="lblProducer"]/text()').extract()
          item ["producer_name"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="lblProducer"]/text()').extract()

          items.append(item)

          print "this is ITEMS"
        return items
```

Below is the log :

```
log>
    {'certificate_date': [],
     'certificate_no': [],
     'length': [],
     'movie_category': [],
     'movie_language': [],
     'movie_name': [],
     'producer_name': [],
     'regional_office': []}
2014-06-11 23:20:44+0530 [movie] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
214-06-11 23:20:44+0530 [movie] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 256,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 6638,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 11, 17, 50, 44, 54000),
     'item_scraped_count': 1,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 11, 17, 50, 43, 681000)}
```

Comment: I can make use of below code to create a list of START_URLS, but I want to do it for i in range(1,1000) , will that create any issues? However, I am unable to scrape the data, ITEMS are still empty start_urls = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        url = 'http://cbfcindia.gov.in/html/SearchDetails.aspx?mid=' + str(i) + '&Loc=Backlog'
        start_urls.append(url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed domains should be defined without the `http://`. For example:

`allowed_domains= ["cbfcindia.gov.in/"]`

If any issues persist, then please show the *full* log that includes details of the pages crawled and any redirects that may have occurred.

Comment: domains should be without trailing slash

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Talvalin's answer, the correct XPath should be of the form:

```
item["movie_name"] = hxs.xpath("//*[@id='lblMovieName']/font/text()").extract()
```

For some reason, when the page loads, the `<font>` tag get separated from the `<span>` tag (or whatever tag the `id` is in). I've tested this and it works.

Word of warning, though: the site is pretty much protected from scraping. I've tried running a second scrape and it immediately threw a `Runtime Error`.